# iterating over characters in a line and replacing them

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, iteration, python-itertools

I have been working on a program that would replace the characters in a line (hhhhhhhhhhghhghhhhhfhhhhhfffffeee[X]b[d[ed`[Y[^Y, in the example) by their decimal ascii equivalent and replace the resulting line. This is what I have so far...

```
f2 = path to file
if re.match('[AGNTC]{5}', line):
    next_line = next(f2)
    unilist.append(next(f2))

    for j in unilist:
        j=[x for x in unilist if x]
        g=[word.strip() for word in j]
        g= ''.join(g)

        for ch in g:
            char= ord(ch)
            char= int(char)
            ch= str(char-33)
```

Everything works to this point.  I just need pointers as I begun learning python not too long ago. I want to put all the ch in one string based on where their corresponding character was located. The f2 file looks a little like:

```
@SRR566546.970 HWUSI-EAS1673_11067_FC7070M:4:1:2299:1109 length=50
TTGCCTGCCTATCATTTTAGTGCCTGTGAGGTGGAGATGTGAGGATCAGT
+SRR566546.970 HWUSI-EAS1673_11067_FC7070M:4:1:2299:1109 length=50
hhhhhhhhhhghhghhhhhfhhhhhfffffeee[X]b[d[ed`[Y[^Y
```

I was thinking of maybe using itertools for the pairing up. I also need to modify the line with the T,G,C, and A so that if the ascii code is less than 20, the corresponding character is replaced by a N. As I mentionned earlier, I just need to know what tools would be the most appropriate for the job and all suggestions and tips are appreciated.

I have tried:

```
for cha in g:
    g.replace(str(cha), ch)
    print(g)
```

But, it prints back the initial line.

**EDIT:**
I have solved my problem with the sequence, but I need to know how to pair the values...

```
   for cha in g:
        char= ord(cha)
        char= int(char)
        ch= str(char-33)
        mylist.append(ch)
mylist=','.join(mylist)
f1.write('%s\n' %mylist)
```

**EDIT:**
I have tried to write a bit:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
burp = random.randrange(0, 100000000000)

f1 = open(path to file)
f3=open(path to file3, 'w+')

for line, next_line in pairwise(f1):

        if re.match ('[AGTCN]{5}', line):
            for ch in next_line:
                if ch<str('20'):
                    for ch in line:
                        line.replace(ch,'N')
            f3.write('%s' %line)

        else:
            if re.match(r'\d{1,1}', line):
                line=''
                f3.write('%s' %line)

            else:
                f3.write('%s' %line)
```

However, I am wondering how I could take into consideration the ',' in between the scores and the ch positions' in both the lines. Right now the output has the 2nd line, not modified or anything...

**EDIT:**
Now, I just need to find a way that the N are actually 'replaced' in the second line based on the ascii score obtained by my latest edit.

Comment: How is your input/output even related?

Comment: @Jon Clements my input is the text given and my program takes the TTGCC... line if matched, skips 2 lines which gives the hhhh... line and appends it to the list (unilist) where every element is taken and the ascii code to every character is returned. At this point, I am just wondering in which way I could pair up the 2nd and 4th lines together... just modules that could be helpful and such ... thanks, and I hope I was clear.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or what you want to do.

Comment: @msnider I want to iterate over the characters of the fourth line in the template and if the ascii decimal score for that character is less than 20, the corresponding character of the second line in the template is replaced by a 'N'.

Comment: It would return the modified second line with the 'N''s... In the example, however it would simply write the fourth line as all characters have a ascii score of over 20 in the fourth line (when 33 is deducted, sorry forgot to mention this much).

Comment: You mean that the ASCII value must be over 53 or 20? What is 33 deducted from?

Comment: @msnider I substract the 33 in the program so it must be over 20 once the substraction has been made.

Comment: I will write a new question since it evolved since I began working on it.

Comment: @Fabien Okay, but please check my answer and see if it helps

Comment: @Fabien please be sure to include input/current output and *desired output* so that people can see what you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is iterate over the second and fourth lines in a file, and change characters in the second line, based on the ASCII value of characters in the fourth line.

Input:

```
@SRR566546.970 HWUSI-EAS1673_11067_FC7070M:4:1:2299:1109 length=50
TTGCCTGCCTATCATTTTAGTGCCTGTGAGGTGGAGATGTGAGGATCAGT
+SRR566546.970 HWUSI-EAS1673_11067_FC7070M:4:1:2299:1109 length=50
hhhhhhhhhhghhghhhhhfhhhhhfffffeee[X]b[d[ed`[Y[^Y
```

Output:

```
@SRR566546.970 HWUSI-EAS1673_11067_FC7070M:4:1:2299:1109 length=50
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
+SRR566546.970 HWUSI-EAS1673_11067_FC7070M:4:1:2299:1109 length=50
hhhhhhhhhhghhghhhhhfhhhhhfffffeee[X]b[d[ed`[Y[^Y
```

Python strings are immutable (they cannot be modified). Read the whole file in, convert the relevant lines to lists, check which characters in the fourth line have an ASCII value greater than 53, and then overwrite the corresponding characters in the second line with `N`'s.

```
# Read file, convert strings to lists
fin = open("path/to/file")
lines = fin.readlines()
line2, line4 = list(lines[1]), list(lines[3])  

# Make the changes to our lists
for i, c in enumerate(line4):
   if( ord(c) > 53 ):
      line2[i] = 'N'

# Overwrite line 2
lines[1] = ''.join(line2)

# Save back to the file
fin.seek(0)
for line in lines:
   fin.write(line)

fin.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, actually all I needed was a way to refer to the index within the line to make it so that the right characters would be changed... and also I had ',' in between the numbers... So I was thinking of using lists ... This sold me on it. I will modify my code accordingly.

Comment: @Fabien No problem. The important thing to remember is the immutability of strings in Python. Lists lend themselves well to a problem like this. Also, using `enumerate()` to keep track of the index in a loop is a useful tactic.

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to do it the lazy way and copy the strings once the operations were done rather than having to join the lists... Yeah, I am that lazy (plus it never hurts to try and find new ways around a problem).